# AngularJS on Thinkster tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying with AngularJS and make some basic on it. This is my view:

```
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div align="center">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
      <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">

        {{post.upvotes}}

            {{post.title}}

            {{post.title}}

      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addPost()">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
        <button type="submit" >Post</button>
      </form>

 </script>

</body>
```

This view handled by app.js:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


        $scope.posts = [
            {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 0},
            {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 0},
            {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 0},
            {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 0},

        ];
        $scope.addPost = function(){
            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
            $scope.posts.push({
                title: $scope.title, 
                upvotes: 0});
            $scope.title = '';
        };

        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post){
            post.upvotes += 1;
        };

});

angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

The **problem** is that the post data is not rendered on page. But if I don't use `ui.router` and `<ui-view>` for rendering template, it's working; (means that data of posts can be displayed on page).

So, what's the issue and how can I rectify with that?

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring your module twice - declaring the module is when you put the second parameter in the module function, while if you just want to reference it, you omit the second parameter.

Basically, your code should be:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']) // declaration here
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


        $scope.posts = [
            {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 0},
            {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 0},
            {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 0},
            {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 0},

        ];
        $scope.addPost = function(){
            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
            $scope.posts.push({
                title: $scope.title, 
                upvotes: 0});
            $scope.title = '';
        };

        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post){
            post.upvotes += 1;
        };

});

angular.module('flapperNews')  // reference only here
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

So in angular

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [list dependencies]);
```

creates a new module and

```
angular.module('flapperNews')//notice there is no array
```

returns the module.

I think you meant to move the `['ui.router']` to the top line of your app.js file.